# SSH using Active Directory credentials

Tags: ssh, active-directory, redhat-enterprise-linux, authentication

I am using AWS, I can ssh using `.pem` file, I have also enabled password login by modifying `/etc/sshd/sshd_config`. I can create a new user and login with that user using password.

However, instead of creating new user every time I would like users to get authenticated from Active Directory. I have a Windows 2012 R2 instance running on AWS where I have configured users in Active Directory.

Comment: The only way I know how to do this would be to use Kerberos and IDM.  You would make IDM trust the Active Domain, allowing you ssh as the "user@ad"@host.  How you accomplish this depends on your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Set up either an AD client (which can act as a full domain member), or a generic LDAP client. Several possible options are:

- winbindd from Samba;
- sssd (using realmd or adcli to join);
- Centrify AD;
- nslcd (nss-ldapd) + pam_krb5.

Setting up one of these and adding to nsswitch.conf will let the system look up AD accounts. Enabling GSSAPIAuthentication in sshd_config will let clients use Kerberos to log in to the server; alternatively, adding the PAM module will let sshd verify plain passwords against AD.